# Reference-Orig: Starting at deepest folders of tree and finding the shallowest Top Level Parent meeting conditions

Tags: powershell

In Powershell the script supposed to be analyzing the deepest sub-folders first to see if they meet conditions.

I can't make it find the top most parent directory of the deepest sub-folders that share the same conditions.
 Conditions: `$allFolders | Where-Object  ($_.ext_allFiles.Count -gt 0 -and $_.NonMusicFileExt_Percentage -le 30 )`. Each of those parameters returns results based on the current folder and its children. Final results I get are only the 1st(deepest) folder it scans when there are  parents...grandparents that meet the conditions too.

Right now for 1 example, I am getting results for Ariana Grande like these when in fact their 2 top parent folders are '.\Ariana Grande 2016 Discography' & '.\Ariana Grande - iTunes Discography'. All music files are m4a's and meet the conditions.

```
Folder of the toplevel_v2: .\Ariana Grande 2016 Discography\Albums\2016 Dangerous Woman (Deluxe) [Clean]
Folder of the toplevel_v2: .\Ariana Grande 2016 Discography\Albums\2014 Yours Truly (Japanese Version)
Folder of the toplevel_v2: .\Ariana Grande 2016 Discography\Albums\2014 My Everything (Japanese Version)
Folder of the toplevel_v2: .\Ariana Grande 2016 Discography\Albums\2014 My Everything (Deluxe)
Folder of the toplevel_v2: .\Ariana Grande 2016 Discography\Albums\2013 Yours Truly
Folder of the toplevel_v2: .\Ariana Grande - iTunes Discography\Studio Albums\2014.08.27 My Everything (Japanese Version)
Folder of the toplevel_v2: .\Ariana Grande - iTunes Discography\Studio Albums\2014.08.25 My Everything (Deluxe)
Folder of the toplevel_v2: .\Ariana Grande - iTunes Discography\Studio Albums\2014.02.05 Yours Truly (Japanese Version)
Folder of the toplevel_v2: .\Ariana Grande - iTunes Discography\Studio Albums\2013.01.01 Yours Truly
Folder of the toplevel_v2: .\Ariana Grande - iTunes Discography\Singles\2014.08.13 Baby I (Feat. Taro Hakase) - Single jp
```

here are more detail logs from my script:

```
---Start of new folder: .\Ariana Grande 2016 Discography\Albums\2014 My Everything (Deluxe)---
This is the ratio: 0% Folder FileCount: 15 NonFileExtension Queue: 0
RandFile count before metadatacheck: 3 RandFiles Found required metadata file. Process entire Folder
Shallowest Matching Depth: 3
---End of Full FolderObj loop Count: 53---

---Start of new folder: .\Ariana Grande 2016 Discography\Albums\2013 Yours Truly---
This is the ratio: 0% Folder FileCount: 13 NonFileExtension Queue: 0
RandFile count before metadatacheck: 2 RandFiles Found required metadata file. Process entire Folder
Shallowest Matching Depth: 3
---End of Full FolderObj loop Count: 54---

---Start of new folder: .\Ariana Grande - iTunes Discography\Studio Albums\2014.08.27 My Everything (Japanese Version)---
This is the ratio: 0% Folder FileCount: 18 NonFileExtension Queue: 0
RandFile count before metadatacheck: 3 RandFiles Found required metadata file. Process entire Folder.
Shallowest Matching Depth: 3
---End of Full FolderObj loop Count: 55---

---Start of new folder: .\Ariana Grande - iTunes Discography\Studio Albums\2014.08.25 My Everything (Deluxe)---
This is the ratio: 0% Folder FileCount: 15 NonFileExtension Queue: 0
RandFile count before metadatacheck: 3 RandFiles Found required metadata file. Process entire Folder
Shallowest Matching Depth: 3
---End of Full FolderObj loop Count: 56---

---Start of new folder: .\Ariana Grande - iTunes Discography\Studio Albums\2014.02.05 Yours Truly (Japanese Version)---
This is the ratio: 0% Folder FileCount: 15 NonFileExtension Queue: 0
RandFile count before metadatacheck: 3 RandFiles Found required metadata file. Process entire Folder
Shallowest Matching Depth: 3
---End of Full FolderObj loop Count: 57---
```

And, these also have the same result:
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD1 Donizetti Arias
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD10 Neapolitan and Italian Popular Songs
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD11 Bonus - The 1964 EP
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD2 Bellini,Donizetti,Verdi
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD3 Verdi 1
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD4 Verdi 2
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD5 Puccini
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD6 Puccini and Verismo
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD7 Arias 1
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD8 Arias 2
Z:\Music!Complete\Pavarotti Edition 10+1BonusCD-Orig\CD9 Italian Songs

The script starts with setting the file extensions that of and are not of interest (to avoid having non-music files being counted with percentage and counts). It then constructs RegEx variables to modify those 2 extensions variables for use to run calculations while analyzing directories. I then create compiled vars for those Regex.

With $MetadataFields I set target metadata fields that will be used by the program exiftool.exe (reading with the tool has different argument formats than the write). The for loop then takes those fields puts it into a single string and adds a dash-per-extension and spaces between them.

I think this might be the most relevant part of the code to the shallowest filtering:

```
$finalFolders = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
foreach ($folderObj in $matchedFolders) {
    $isChild = $false
    foreach ($folderPath in $FolderTable.Keys) {
        if ($folderObj.FullName.StartsWith($folderPath) -and $folderObj.FullName -ne $folderPath) {
            $isChild = $true
            break
        }
    }
    if (-not $isChild) {
    [void]$finalFolders.Add($folderObj)
    }
}

foreach ($folderObj in $finalFolders) {
    Write-Color "This is the ratio: $($folderObj.NonMusicFileExt_Percentage)%   ","Folder FileCount: ","$($folderObj.Files.Count)","    NonFileExtension Queue: ","$($folderObj.nonExtAllFilesCount)"-Color DarkGray,DarkYellow,DarkGray,DarkYellow,DarkGray
    if (($folderObj.ext_Files.Count -eq 0) -and ($folderObj.ext_allFiles.Count -gt 0) -and ($folderObj.NonMusicFileExt_Percentage -le 30)) {
        $folderRelDepth = $folderObj.Depth - ($sourceDirectory -split '\\').Count
    } elseif ($folderObj.ext_Files.Count -gt 0) {
        $randfiles = Get-RandomFilesBard -ext_Files $($folderObj.ext_Files) -ext_FilesCount $($folderObj.ext_Files.Count)
        if ($randFiles.Count -eq 0) {continue } else {
            if (HasMetadataFields -FilePath $randFiles) {
                # Use the top-level parent instead of the immediate parent
                $folderRelDepth = $folderObj.Depth - ($sourceDirectory -split '\\').Count
            }
        }
    }

    if (($folderRelDepth -le $shallowestMatchingFolderDepth)) {
        $shallowestMatchingFolderDepth = $folderRelDepth
        $TopMostMatchingFolder = ".\$([System.IO.Path]::GetRelativePath($sourceDirectory, $folderObj.FullName))"
        [void]$TopLevelFolderTable.Add($folderObj.FullName)

        [System.Console]::WriteLine("Shallowest Matching Depth: $($shallowestMatchingFolderDepth)")
        [System.Console]::WriteLine("The Matching Folder: $TopMostMatchingFolder")
```

This is a larger part of the code for context:

```
$sourceDirectory = Get-Location
$FileExtensions = @('.m4a', '.alac')
$nonFileMusicExts = @('.3gp', '.aiff', '.ape', '.dsd', '.flac', '.mp3', '.mp4', '.ra', '.ogg', '.opus', '.tta', '.wav', '.wma', '.wv')
# Join the extensions into a single regular expression
$FileExtensionsRegex = '\.(' + (($FileExtensions -replace '\.', '') -join '|') + ')$'
# Combine file extensions and non-file music extensions into a single regex pattern
$CombinedExtensions = $FileExtensions + $nonFileMusicExts
$CombinedExtensionsRegex = '\.(' + (($CombinedExtensions -replace '\.', '') -join '|') + ')$'
$compilFileExtensionsRegex = [regex]::new($FileExtensionsRegex, [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Compiled)
$compilCombinedExtsRegex = [regex]::new($CombinedExtensionsRegex, [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Compiled) 
$MetadataFields = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new() 
[void]$MetadataFields.Add( [string[]]("AppleStoreCountry","AppleStoreAccountType","Certificate","AppleStoreCatalogID") )
# Get the final concatenated string
$metaDataFieldList = $metaDataFieldList.ToString()
$shallowestMatchingFolderDepth = [int]::MaxValue
# Get all directories and files
Write-Color "Indexing Directories and Files..."-Color DarkYellow
$folderPaths = [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($sourceDirectory, "*", [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)
$allDirectoriesAndFiles = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFileSystemEntries($sourceDirectory, "*.*", [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)
$lookupTable = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]]::new()
#Build the lookup table
foreach ($path in $allDirectoriesAndFiles) {
    # Check if the entry is a file
    if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($path)) {
        # If it's a file, add it to the lookup table for its directory and all parent directories
        $directory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($path)
        while ($null -ne $directory -and $directory.StartsWith($sourceDirectory) -and $directory -ne '') {
            if (-not $lookupTable.ContainsKey($directory)) {
                $lookupTable[$directory] = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
                }
                [void]$lookupTable[$directory].Add($path)
                # Move up to the parent directory
                $directory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($directory)
        }
    }
}

$allFolders = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$matchedFolders = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$TopLevelFolderTable = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()
# Loop through each folder and process them
foreach ($folderPath in $folderPaths) {
    $allNonfiles_and_Files = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
    $Depth = ($folderPath.Split('\')).Count
    $allFiles = $lookupTable[$folderPath]
    if ($allFiles -eq $null) { Continue } 
    $allNonfiles_and_Files = $allFiles | Where-Object { $compilCombinedExtsRegex.IsMatch($_) }
    $Files = $allFiles | Where-Object { (Split-Path $_ -Parent) -eq $folderPath }
    $Nonfiles_and_Files = $Files | Where-Object { $compilCombinedExtsRegex.IsMatch($_)  }
    if ($allNonfiles_and_Files.Count -le 0) { continue
    } else {
        $ext_AllFiles = $allNonfiles_and_Files | Where-Object { $compilFileExtensionsRegex.IsMatch($_) }
        $ext_Files = $Nonfiles_and_Files | Where-Object { $_ -match $FileExtensionsRegex }
        $nonExtAllFilesCount = $allNonfiles_and_Files.Count - $ext_AllFiles.Count
        $NonMusicFileExt_Percentage = [Math]::Round(($nonExtAllFilesCount / $allNonfiles_and_Files.Count)*100,2)
            if ($Nonfiles_and_Files.Count -le 0) {continue} else {
                $currentFolderFilesPercentage = [Math]::Round(($ext_Files.Count / $Nonfiles_and_Files.Count) * 100, 2)
            }
            $folderObj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                FullName = $folderPath
                Depth = $Depth
                AllFiles = $allNonfiles_and_Files ;                     Files = $Nonfiles_and_Files  ;
                ext_AllFiles = $ext_AllFiles ;                          ext_Files =  $ext_Files ;           ext_FileCount = $ext_Files.Count
                nonExtAllFilesCount = $nonExtAllFilesCount
                NonMusicFileExt_Percentage = $NonMusicFileExt_Percentage
                CurrentFolderFilesPercentage = $currentFolderFilesPercentage
                Match = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
            }
            [void]$allFolders.Add($folderObj)
    }
}

# Now we have a list of folder objects
$matchedFolders = $allFolders | Where-Object { $_.ext_AllFiles.Count -gt 0 -and (($_.NonFileExtensionPercentage -le 30) -or ($_.ext_FilesCount -gt 0)) } | Sort-Object Depth -Descending
$FolderTable = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,object]]::new()
foreach ($folderObj in $matchedFolders) {
    [void]$FolderTable.Add($folderObj.FullName, $folderObj)
}
[System.Console]::WriteLine("Refining - to Parents...") 
# Create a new array to hold the final folder objects
$finalFolders = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
foreach ($folderObj in $matchedFolders) {
    $isChild = $false
    foreach ($folderPath in $FolderTable.Keys) {
        if ($folderObj.FullName.StartsWith($folderPath) -and $folderObj.FullName -ne $folderPath) {
            $isChild = $true
            break
        }
    }
    if (-not $isChild) {
    [void]$finalFolders.Add($folderObj)
    }
}

foreach ($folderObj in $finalFolders) {
    Write-Color "This is the ratio: $($folderObj.NonMusicFileExt_Percentage)%   ","Folder FileCount: ","$($folderObj.Files.Count)","    NonFileExtension Queue: ","$($folderObj.nonExtAllFilesCount)"-Color DarkGray,DarkYellow,DarkGray,DarkYellow,DarkGray
    if (($folderObj.ext_Files.Count -eq 0) -and ($folderObj.ext_allFiles.Count -gt 0) -and ($folderObj.NonMusicFileExt_Percentage -le 30)) {
        $folderRelDepth = $folderObj.Depth - ($sourceDirectory -split '\\').Count
    } elseif ($folderObj.ext_Files.Count -gt 0) {
        $randfiles = Get-RandomFilesBard -ext_Files $($folderObj.ext_Files) -ext_FilesCount $($folderObj.ext_Files.Count)
        if ($randFiles.Count -eq 0) {continue } else {
            if (HasMetadataFields -FilePath $randFiles) {
                # Use the top-level parent instead of the immediate parent
                $folderRelDepth = $folderObj.Depth - ($sourceDirectory -split '\\').Count
            }
        }
    }

    if (($folderRelDepth -le $shallowestMatchingFolderDepth)) {
        $shallowestMatchingFolderDepth = $folderRelDepth
        $TopMostMatchingFolder = ".\$([System.IO.Path]::GetRelativePath($sourceDirectory, $folderObj.FullName))"
        [void]$TopLevelFolderTable.Add($folderObj.FullName)

        [System.Console]::WriteLine("Shallowest Matching Depth: $($shallowestMatchingFolderDepth)")
        [System.Console]::WriteLine("The Matching Folder: $TopMostMatchingFolder")
        
    }
}

#A console summary of Folders found
ForEach ($item2 in $TopLevelFolderTable) {
    $item2 = ".\$([System.IO.Path]::GetRelativePath($sourceDirectory, $item2))"
    [System.Console]::WriteLine("Folder of the toplevel_v2: $item2")
} ; [System.Console]::WriteLine("---- TotalFolders: $TopLevelFolderTable.Count ")
```

Comment: there are 227 lines of code in your question, can you please summarize and ask a more concise and specific question ?

Comment: Hopefully that can be acceptable, I'm not sure what else to remove without taking out relevant code for other to understand?

Comment: That’s still a big old jumble of code - you’d do yourself a major service by refactoring it into a number of independent and *testable* (with e.g. Pester) functions - *future you* will thank *present you* when you come back to it in a year’s time and you can’t remember how any of it works :-).